# disable all click events till ajax request is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, event-handling

So I have a listing page something like this:

```
//start loop
<div id ='row-prd-<number>'>
  <strong>product Name</strong>
  <a href='#' id='edit-prd-<number>'>Edit</a>
  <a href='#' id='delete-prd-<number>'>Delete</a>
</div>
//end loop
```

In my javascript, I do something like:

```
$('#delete-prd-<number>').click()
{
   //change style of the row to show its being deleted..
   $('row-prd-<number>').addClass('deleting');

   //make ajax call to delete
   ajaxDeleteRecord(prd-<number>);
}
```

Now, this works fine. My concern is that in a lower connection speed scenario, the delete ajax call takes a few seconds to complete. I am concerned about what happens if the user clicks on an edit or delete button of another record. So I have three questions:

***1. Should I disable all click events on the page until the ajax call returns?***
To me this does not seem like a good option - suppose the ajax call errored out...in that case the user now is in a state where s/he cannot click on anything in the page anymore!

***2. How then should I handle this?***
...I am kinda just lost as to what to do. I guess this is the most important of the three questions I have.

***1. If I had to disable and re-enable clicks on the elements on the page (edit/delete/new) is there an easy way to do it?***
...just curious...

Comment: What about making your AJAX call synchronous? It would block everything else until the AJAX call returns.

Comment: hmm...thats a very good suggestion. I guess I will have to handle the ajax response breaking in any scenario anyways...

Comment: Consider handling the error conditions, instead of making the browser unresponsive by making your request synchronous. Lookup the `error` callback option in `$.ajax()`

Answer (score -1):

your scenario 1 will do the trick in order to do disable all the other events. It will be kind of neat as well.

You can have another thing to have the ajax call be synchronous rather than being asynchronous by setting

```
async:false
```

in the call.

The syntax would look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'your url',
        global: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {},
        async: false,
        success: function() {},
        error: function() {}
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! How would you handle a situation where the ajax response does not come back? I do not want the users to be stuck without being able to do anything...

Comment: That can be handled in the error block of the same ajax request. an ajax request has to be come back either as an error or a success.

Comment: what's the benefit of ajax if it has to be made synchronous??

Comment: @Anant the ajax call is to get the data or push data, however sometimes it is required to wait for the response, (disabling the buttons/or making the file upload and give the upload progress) which needs to be synchronous..using ajax is not just having asynchronous usage...thats y for certain use cases they have given the parameter async:false...

Comment: @v31 but there could be better solution to disable all clicks, rather making ajax synchronous. What if server didn't respond? That will just freeze the page. In this case user will have no clue what is going on. May be synchronous state is perfect in some other scenario, but not in the present scenario

Comment: @Anant: you are correct, there may be a better solution, however the answer which I had given is not incorrect, it is a correct answer though I agree not the best one. (answered 2 years back so can be excused :) )